# I can't decode a url encoded in unknow format on an ASP site

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, utf-8

I'm scraping through a website and this website has a form the form is in the Arabic language so it's encoding everything (inputs) to let the form get work properly

MY problem is I'm scraping using JS and **decodeUri/decodeUriComponent** not working with the encoding output string that coming from the site.

even the browser says `unable to decode value` in console dev

the link example that I need to get it decoded:

> http://app2.helwan.edu.eg/HelwanNat/Education/TermAlist.asp?x_level=2020%2D2019&z_level=LIKE&x_dep=%C7%E1%DA%E1%E6%E3+%2D%CA%DA%E1%ED%E3+%C7%D3%C7%D3%EC&z_dep=LIKE&x_st_name=%E3%CD%E3%CF&z_st_name=LIKE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a **windows-1256** encoding.

You can decode it in js like so:

```js
function decode(string) {
  var array = [...string.matchAll(/%(.{2})/g)].map((groups) => parseInt(groups[1], 16));
  var decoder = new TextDecoder('windows-1256');
  return decoder.decode(Uint8Array.from(array).buffer);
}
console.log(decode('%E3%CD%E3%CF'));
console.log('%C7%E1%DA%E1%E6%E3+%2D%CA%DA%E1%ED%E3+%C7%D3%C7%D3%EC'.split('+').map(decode));
```

Since [TextEncoder()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder/TextEncoder) can only encode **utf-8** strings, you will have to make a conversion table for [windows-1256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1256#Character_set):

```js
windows_1256 = [
'\u0000', '\u0001', '\u0002', '\u0003', '\u0004', '\u0005', '\u0006', '\u0007', '\u0008', '\u0009', '\u000A', '\u000B', '\u000C', '\u000D', '\u000E', '\u000F',
'\u0010', '\u0011', '\u0012', '\u0013', '\u0014', '\u0015', '\u0016', '\u0017', '\u0018', '\u0019', '\u001A', '\u001B', '\u001C', '\u001D', '\u001E', '\u001F',
'\u0020', '\u0021', '\u0022', '\u0023', '\u0024', '\u0025', '\u0026', '\u0027', '\u0028', '\u0029', '\u002A', '\u002B', '\u002C', '\u002D', '\u002E', '\u002F',
'\u0030', '\u0031', '\u0032', '\u0033', '\u0034', '\u0035', '\u0036', '\u0037', '\u0038', '\u0039', '\u003A', '\u003B', '\u003C', '\u003D', '\u003E', '\u003F',
'\u0040', '\u0041', '\u0042', '\u0043', '\u0044', '\u0045', '\u0046', '\u0047', '\u0048', '\u0049', '\u004A', '\u004B', '\u004C', '\u004D', '\u004E', '\u004F',
'\u0050', '\u0051', '\u0052', '\u0053', '\u0054', '\u0055', '\u0056', '\u0057', '\u0058', '\u0059', '\u005A', '\u005B', '\u005C', '\u005D', '\u005E', '\u005F',
'\u0060', '\u0061', '\u0062', '\u0063', '\u0064', '\u0065', '\u0066', '\u0067', '\u0068', '\u0069', '\u006A', '\u006B', '\u006C', '\u006D', '\u006E', '\u006F',
'\u0070', '\u0071', '\u0072', '\u0073', '\u0074', '\u0075', '\u0076', '\u0077', '\u0078', '\u0079', '\u007A', '\u007B', '\u007C', '\u007D', '\u007E', '\u007F',
'\u20AC', '\u067E', '\u201A', '\u0192', '\u201E', '\u2026', '\u2020', '\u2021', '\u02C6', '\u2030', '\u0679', '\u2039', '\u0152', '\u0686', '\u0698', '\u0688',
'\u06AF', '\u2018', '\u2019', '\u201C', '\u201D', '\u2022', '\u2013', '\u2014', '\u06A9', '\u2122', '\u0691', '\u203A', '\u0153', '\u200C', '\u200D', '\u06BA',
'\u00A0', '\u060C', '\u00A2', '\u00A3', '\u00A4', '\u00A5', '\u00A6', '\u00A7', '\u00A8', '\u00A9', '\u06BE', '\u00AB', '\u00AC', '\u00AD', '\u00AE', '\u00AF',
'\u00B0', '\u00B1', '\u00B2', '\u00B3', '\u00B4', '\u00B5', '\u00B6', '\u00B7', '\u00B8', '\u00B9', '\u061B', '\u00BB', '\u00BC', '\u00BD', '\u00BE', '\u061F',
'\u06C1', '\u0621', '\u0622', '\u0623', '\u0624', '\u0625', '\u0626', '\u0627', '\u0628', '\u0629', '\u062A', '\u062B', '\u062C', '\u062D', '\u062E', '\u062F',
'\u0630', '\u0631', '\u0632', '\u0633', '\u0634', '\u0635', '\u0636', '\u00D7', '\u0637', '\u0638', '\u0639', '\u063A', '\u0640', '\u0641', '\u0642', '\u0643',
'\u00E0', '\u0644', '\u00E2', '\u0645', '\u0646', '\u0647', '\u0648', '\u00E7', '\u00E8', '\u00E9', '\u00EA', '\u00EB', '\u0649', '\u064A', '\u00EE', '\u00EF',
'\u064B', '\u064C', '\u064D', '\u064E', '\u00F4', '\u064F', '\u0650', '\u00F7', '\u0651', '\u00F9', '\u0652', '\u00FB', '\u00FC', '\u200E', '\u200F', '\u06D2'
];

function encode(string){
    return [...string].map(c => `%${windows_1256.indexOf(c).toString(16).toUpperCase()}`).join('');
}
console.log(encode('محمد'));
console.log(['العلوم', "-تعليم", "اساسى"].map(encode).join('+'));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot working great, but If I wanna encode it again how I can reverse this